# I'm a newbie. Import a .txt file to datagridview

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer, c#-5.0

According to my assignment , I need a openfiledialog to open a .txt file them I need it loaded on datagridview in , any ideas , I know that I have to split rows and columns but I don’t know the code , just the beginner in freshman

Comment: Post sample code and don't declare yourself a newbie in the title, no one cares.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by looking into System.IO.StringReader to read the file. Then you just need to split that up however you have been told, and save those values into DataGridViewCells which can be added to the DataGridView.